# Can't import a project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio. I am facing some problems regarding Gradle.

I tried to import this project from github: https://github.com/saulmm/Android-Material-Example, but got this error message:

> Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Android-Material-Example-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

This is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } }
```

And this is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

I can't find `runProguard()` they are talking about! Any solutions?

Comment: check your each `build.gradle` files and replace the occurences of `runProguard()` to `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: Within the **app** folder in that Github project is a **build.gradle** file with the line `runProguard false`. Change this line to read `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: You're right, I was checking the wrong build.gradle file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one in the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

        /**
        *
        * Here is the change that must be done
        *
        **/
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

buildscript {

}

repositories {

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it gives me: 'Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar'. I'm running on a device of Android API16 installed, but compileSdkVersion is much higher.

Comment: Please, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar 
Perhaps it can help you