# ToolBar Widget in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Hi I am trying to learn Material design and was stuck up with the Toolbar code.I am confused in which library to use and Why its showing this error

**Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Toolbar**

For this I am using the support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

If u have any idea of how to solve this error plz share me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you import the appcompat library?

Comment: please show us your code where you set it and your styles.xml

Comment: you need `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You need appCompat Support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7-XXXX // XXXX is the version , choose latest.
```

Couple of more suggestions, if you can't make it work by adding above Services.

- Add all services of the same version.
- Clean the project.

More suggestion in below link, this is similar question.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27007448/519718)