# Starting FragmentActivity from AsynTask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

This is my class file which extends FragmentActivity. I am not quite sure if I am doing it right. I want to have a tabbed layout in this activity but the app keeps crashing.

````
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });

    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments [] = {"A","B"};

        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0: return new fragment1();
                case 1: return new fragment2();
                default:return null;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }


When I pass an intent from the AsynTask like so

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(m_context, booking.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    m_context.startActivity(intent);```

My app builds but crashes with the error
````

```

> Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.TabView
>
> 02-23 16:54:11.061 14404-14404/com.example.application_name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.application_name, PID: 14404
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.application_name/com.example.application_name.booking}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.TabView
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7:
>   Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.TabView
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>                                                                                      at com.example.webook.webook.booking.onCreate(booking.java:29)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.TabView" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.webook.webook-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.webook.webook-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                      at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                                      at com.example.webook.webook.booking.onCreate(booking.java:29) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)```

This is my Asyntask

```
package com.example.webook.webook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by bhargavpanth on 10/02/16.
 */
public class LoginAsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    Context m_context;
    String m_name,m_email,m_password;

    public LoginAsyncTask(Context context, String email, String pasword){
        m_context = context;
        m_email=email;
        m_password=pasword;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Looper.prepare();
        try{
            final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(m_context);
            JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
                jsonobject.put("csrf_token", "");
                js.put("params", jsonobject);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //https://webook.trabacus.com/webook/csrf_token
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,"https://webook.trabacus.com/webook/csrf_token", js,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
//                            Log.d("tagd", response.result.csrf_token());
                            try{
                                JSONObject ob=response.getJSONObject("result");
                                String csrf=ob.getString("csrf_token");
                                //rid,csrf,name,email,password
                                JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
                                    jsonobject.put("csrf_token",csrf);
                                    jsonobject.put("login",m_email);
                                    jsonobject.put("password",m_password);
                                    jsonobject.put("db","Odoo-9");

                                    js.put("params", jsonobject);
                                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://webook.trabacus.com/webook/login", js, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                            Log.d("tagd", response.toString());
                                            Intent intent;
                                            intent = new Intent(m_context, booking.class);
                                            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            m_context.startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    },
                                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                    Log.d("tagd",error.toString());
                                                }
                                            }){
                                        @Override
                                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                                            HashMap<String,String> headers=new HashMap<>();
                                            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
                                            return headers;
                                        }

                                    };
                                    queue.add(jsonObjReq);

                                }catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                Log.d("tagd",ob.getString("csrf_token"));
                            }catch (Exception e){

                            }
//                            msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
//                            hideProgressDialog();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("tagd", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
//                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

                /**
                 * Passing some request headers
                 */
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(jsonObjReq);
//            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://webook.trabacus.com/webook/csrf_token", new Response.Listener<String>() {
//                @Override
//                public void onResponse(String response) {
//                    Log.d("tagd",response);
//                }
//            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                    Toast.makeText(m_context,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                }
//            }){
//                @Override
//                protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
//                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                    params.put("csrf_token","");
//                    return params;
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
//                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//                    return params;
//                }
//            };
//            queue.add();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(m_context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```

Comment: What is the error exactly? please show the entire stack trace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27007448/3817374 You can check for this

Comment: Starting an activity is a UI task, which should not be done in doInBackground() method of AsyncTask. Use onPostExecute to do UI related work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doInBackground` is running in non-ui thread. You cant do ui operations in this.

Either use this in push activity operation in `onPostExecute` method
 or use the following

```
runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {
             Intent intent= new Intent(m_context, booking.class);
    m_context.startActivity(intent);
         }
     }));
```

Comment: ```onPostExecute``` did the job, the issue was with my other activity that I was calling.