# New Project crashes due to error in inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Tags: android

```
Here is my Logcat error
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
there is no code in activity class  and this is xml 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.newdemopro.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

only appcompat.v7 library is use in this project  and it crashes at       first start...

```
i tried it many times from googling but i still don't get it..
```

when i update my SDK and update android supporting library to latest version then the problem occur in eclipse and now it crashes all the project which are  new as wee

Comment: How about copying the logcat next time? The important (right) part is missing making it useless.

Comment: the important part? which one?

Comment: The whole text. We only see half of it. "AndroidRuntime" tells us nothing.

Comment: please check now, i replace all images to new

Comment: it says error inflating toolbar but your layout xml do not have toolbar. share the right xml

Comment: Also share your MainActivity even if you say that you have no code in there (it can't be for real, some code must exist in the Activity!)

Comment: ok have to have this question again,  with log cat , xml and activity class

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

(What about the Toolbar supplied by appcompat as the default action bar?)

On API 19 missing `abc_ic_ab_back_material`, which is a vector drawable introduced in appcompat-v7 23.2.

You have 3 options:

**a)** Go back to 23.1.1 which doesn't use vector compat.

**b)** Find a way to pass `"--no-version-vectors"` argument to aapt while building project. This will keep vector drawables even before Lollipop.

**c)** Move to Android Studio asap. Then follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624744/2444099

**d)** Update support libs to 23.2.1 which doesn't force you to use vector compat according to http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html.

Comment: Version 23.2.1 has been published last night, update to that. It doesn't use vector compat so you should have no issues in this matter.