# exceptions with the first call

Tags: android, android-layout

I've just created the newes android app and without changing anything I started it on my smartphone.

I'm getting the following sequence of exceptions and cannot understand what I've done wrong (actually I haven't done anything at all). I have only the default main activity, amin_activity layout and even the default launch icon.

Activity code (created automatically):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Activity layout (created automatically):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I receive the following sequnce of exceptions that are all unhappy in the place where I set the layout (line of code marked with **).

```
04-29 12:33:12.812  17450-17450/? E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
        ...
04-29 12:33:12.949  17450-17450/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.escosautomation.escoslight/de.escosautomation.escoslight.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           ...
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            ...
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
            ...
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            ...
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar

Comment: Do you try change the AppTheme in the styles source? something like this Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar