# android gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to gradle 3.0.0-alpha2

With stacktrace

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

What I have tried:

- reimporting project
- cleaning up
- running without proguard --> it works but I need proguard

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to proguard

```
-keep class android.support.v4.widget.** { *; }
```

(This is similar to [android gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215368/android-gradle-plugin-3-0-0-alpha2-error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-wid) )

Comment: I get the same error but in Eclipse. How would I fix it there?